# dev site redirects to live

Tags: magento-community, redirect, server

Any store related url I try to load on the dev site redirects to the live store.

1) dev is on a **different server**
2) local.xml **mysql** using **new credentials**
3) **base urls** have been **changed**
4) var/**cache removed**
5) browser history/cache/cookies wiped as well as using multiple browsers FF, Chrome and IE
6) fresh copy of .htaccess to ensure no redirects are setup

Any non magento urls will work just fine, such as any text or html file I create.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Please try this in a different browser and let me know if it is still happening.

Comment: once check in core_config_data table.once login into phpmyadmin and go to your database .locate core_config_data table.Locate the rows web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url and click the edit button next to the corresponding lines.  Change the base URL to the intended string, and press ok.

Comment: @ZenMasta You can also try to look .htaccess file in the root directory, if there is any redirect rule is set then also this type of redirection can happen.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was permission related. The var folder needed to be changed to www-data user. Although, I had installed suphp in attempt to avoid having to chown to www-data. It's working for now, I'll have to figure out suphp later I guess.

Comment: feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it is now working,

Comment: Care to share actually why this would cause a redirect? I've seen similar issues (that happened to a friend) and wonder if it was the same cause.

Comment: I honestly have no idea as to WHY, all I know is at the time, that's what set everything right again. Didn't have the time or interest to dig much deeper than that.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple answers to this over on stackexchange, one as follows:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871159/magento-redirection-problem-after-moving

With particular need for checking permissions:

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144268/722112

Apparently Magento used the 'temp' directory in the server-root for caching as well.
cleaning this would solve the issue. This is of course also taken care of when rebooting the server.

Make sure your webserver has write access to the `var`, `var/cache` and `var/tmp` folder in your magento installation.
Try using `chmod -R 700 var` or `chmod -R 766` (use the latter with caution).

**NOTE:** This is the result of not having your file/directory permissions properly set. Magento tries to use var/cache and var/tmp, finds them unwritable by the web server user and proceeds to move its cache to the system /tmp folder. No matter how much you curse and change the BaseURL settings and erase anything you find in var/cache, Magento continues to read the cached configuration out of the system /tmp folder.

Don't believe that Linux Server Admin 101 problems cause this? Here's visual proof.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^devsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newsiteurldmainUrl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

More details http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/